# How do I use RequestClose in IDialogAware in Prism 7.2.0.1367 for Xamarin Forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I have been following the Prism 7.2.0.1367 [release notes.](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases/tag/v7.2.0.1367) I am able to navigate to a dialog ViewModel using `dialogService.ShowDialog(NavigationStrings.MyViewModel)`. But when I close it, I get a null reference exception on RequestClose.

I have a ViewModel like so in my Xamarin Forms project:

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel, IDialogAware, IAutoInitialize
{
    private DelegateCommand _closeCommand;

    public DelegateCommand CloseCommand => _closeCommand ?? (_closeCommand = new DelegateCommand(Close));

    public event Action<IDialogParameters> RequestClose;

    public MyViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService) { }

    public override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
    }

    private void Close()
    {
        RequestClose(null);
    }

    public bool CanCloseDialog() => true;

    public void OnDialogClosed()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Demo Dialog has been closed...");
    }

    public void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters)
    {
        // No need to do anything as IAutoInitialize will take care of what we need here...
    }
}
```

What am I supposed to set RequestClose to to stop it from being null? None of the documentation says anything about having to set this event.

Answer (score 0):

`RequestClose` is `null` because you never subscribe to this event.
You should test if `RequestClose` is null before calling `RequestClose(null)`.

You can subscribe to this event if you want to handle the closing with a custom behavior.

Edited with the check if the action is null :

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel, IDialogAware, IAutoInitialize
{
    private DelegateCommand _closeCommand;

    public DelegateCommand CloseCommand => _closeCommand ?? (_closeCommand = new DelegateCommand(Close));

    public event Action<IDialogParameters> RequestClose;

    public MyViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService) { }

    public override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
    }

    private void Close()
    {
        RequestClose?.Invoke(null);
    }

    public bool CanCloseDialog() => true;

    public void OnDialogClosed()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Demo Dialog has been closed...");
    }

    public void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters)
    {
        // No need to do anything as IAutoInitialize will take care of what we need here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. And if I don't need any custom behavior?

Comment: Just comment the RequestClose(null)

Comment: I'm afraid that does not work. RequestClose is used with IDialogAware in Prism to close dialogs. You call it in a command from your UI.

Comment: I've edited my answer with the null check of the action (in the Close method)

Comment: I guess the framework should have subscribed to the event, and, in theory, it's guaranteed not to be null while the view model lives.

Comment: I've found a workaround for it that involves providing the ShowDialog method with a callback for when it's closed, but I don't feel that this should be necessary. You can read my issue here: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1883

Answer (score 0):

Pass the "CallBack" when navigating. Ex:

```
dialogService.ShowDialog("DialogView", CloseDialogCallback);

void CloseDialogCallback(IDialogResult dialogResult)
    {

    }
```